# Clean way to write a constructor that takes an options object and has defaults?

Tags: typescript

What is a clean way to write a constructor that takes an options object and has defaults?

My best attempt is below

```
export class Client {
    host: string = 'ws://127.0.0.1';
    port: number = 8080;
    logger: (...args: any[]) => void = function() {
        const prefix = "LOG:";
        console.log.call(null, prefix, ...Array.from(arguments))
    };
    maxTime: number = 30000;
    startFromTransactionId: number = 1;
    transactionsCounter: number = 0;
    requestCallbacks: object = {};
    socket: object = {}; 

    constructor(options: {
        host: string, 
        port: number, 
        logger: (...args: any[]) => void , 
        maxTime: number, 
        startFromTransactionId: number
    }) {
        if (options.host) this.host = options.host;
        if (options.port) this.port = options.port;
        if (options.logger) this.logger = options.logger;
        if (options.maxTime) this.maxTime = options.maxTime;
        if (options.startFromTransactionId) this.startFromTransactionId = options.startFromTransactionId;
    }
}
```

In my solution I don't like that:

- I write type annotations for each property twice (one time for the options object and one time for the newly created object)
- I have if statements for each optional parameter

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of cases, I like composition better:

```
export class ClientOptions {
  host: string = 'ws:127.0.0.1';
  port: number = 8080;
  ...
}

export class Client {
  public options: ClientOptions;
  public socket: object = {};
  ...

  constructor(public options: ClientOptions = new ClientOptions()) {
    // options is automatically assigned due to `public` keyword in constructor declaration
    ...
  }
}
```

If you would rather have `this.host` instead of `this.options.host`, you can do:

```
export class ClientOptions {
  host: string = 'ws:127.0.0.1';
  port: number = 8080;
  ...
}

export class Client extends ClientOptions {      
  public socket: object = {};
  ...

  constructor(options: ClientOptions = new ClientOptions()) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you assign the default options?

Comment: For default value, you can make `ClientOptions` a class instead of an interface, or a add a default value object in constructor params. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That looks pretty nice! How would you do if you don't want to have this.options, but rather this.host, this.port and so on?

Comment: @user1283776 I would do something like `Object.assign(this, options)` in constructor. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think your solution looks pretty good. The only downside I can see is that Client extends ClientOptions which to me does not make sense semantically if I think that a "subclass is superclass" like "chair is a furniture" while client is not a cliontOptions.

Comment: I agree, this is why I prefer to use composition instead of inheritance in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help:

```
export class Client {
    public host: string = 'ws://127.0.0.1';
    public port: number = 8080;
    public logger: (...args: any[]) => void = function () {
        const prefix = "LOG:";
        console.log.call(null, prefix, ...Array.from(arguments))
    };
    public maxTime: number = 30000;
    public startFromTransactionId: number = 1;
    public transactionsCounter: number = 0;
    public requestCallbacks: object = {};
    public socket: object = {};

    constructor(options: Client) {
        Object.keys(options).forEach((key) => {
            if (options[key]) {
                this[key] = options[key];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In case you don't want the options to accept all the properties of the Client

```
export class Base {
    public host: string = 'ws://127.0.0.1';
    public port: number = 8080;
    public logger: (...args: any[]) => void = function () {
        const prefix = "LOG:";
        console.log.call(null, prefix, ...Array.from(arguments))
    };
    public maxTime: number = 30000;
    public startFromTransactionId: number = 1;
    public transactionsCounter: number = 0;
}

export class Client extends Base {
    public requestCallbacks: object = {};
    public socket: object = {};

    constructor(options: Base) {
        super();
        Object.keys(options).forEach((key) => {
            if (options[key]) {
                this[key] = options[key];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A weakness with this solution is that the type assertion for options will allow an option with transactionsCounter /requestCallbacks/socket properties, when it should not

Comment: then you can create another class which contains the only necessary option, and extends the class client from it, and also use that class for the options. You can see it in my edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! I am not a fan of the second approach either. It seems semantially wrong to me that Client inherits from a base class without "a client being a base". Base is just some data for client.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way...

```
interface ConnectOptions {
  dburl:string;
  connectionTimeoutMillis:number;
}

const defaultOptions: ConnectOptions = {
  dburl: "",
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 3000
} 

function connect(options: Partial<ConnectOptions>) {
  const effectiveOptions = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options) as ConnectOptions;
  console.log(effectiveOptions.dburl);
  console.log(effectiveOptions.connectionTimeoutMillis);
}

connect({ dburl: "http://mydb/" });
connect({ connectionTimeoutMillis: 1000 });
connect({ dburl: "http://mydb/", connectionTimeoutMillis: 1000 });
```